# Powershell - get only the thumbprint

Tags: powershell

I've seen this asked numerous times before (sorry), but none of the solutions I've found seem to work for me... I want *just* the thumbprint, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I follow everyone else's examples

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My `
   | where{$_.Subject -eq "CN=*XXXXXXXX"}
```

This seems to get me close, but I don't understand how to get *only* the thumbprint

Could someone point me in the right direction? Been reading for the past day on how to get this done, forgive my ignorance

Comment: pipe the result to `| ForEach-Object Thumbprint`

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, I found a solution quickly after posting, heh

```
$Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq "XXXXXXX"}).Thumbprint -join ';';Write-Host -Object "$Thumbprint";
```